# Missing .csproj file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2019 all files like .aspx, .aspx.cs, .js, images are showing. I am missing .csproj and .sln files. to open and try to complie. What might have happened? any sort of idea appreciated.

Comment: Did you perhaps open as a folder, rather than opening the solution? Do you even see the .csproj and .sln files on your explorer?

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto: No. Even in file explorer these two are missing. or not seen.

Comment: Projectname.csproj.user file is showing in file explorer. whereas error of not load file name is projectname.csproj. any help please.

Comment: @tomtom: I am sorry if i wasted your precious time. fact is i have not yet started with project. pretty new to pick it for messing. once again sorry but i really in need of help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a new project and copy the files from the old project to the new project.

Cheers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Diogo Alpendre to choose empty or Web forms template?

Comment: I guess resolved. but need to look into deep for getting compiled.

Comment: Create a new project just like the one that is corrupted, and then copy the files from the corrupted project to the clean one.

Answer (score -1):

Pick one:

1. You deleted them by accident.
2. Some other software (or add-on) you were messing with deleted them.
3. Whatever you actually did is something that normally will not lead to the creation of .csproj/.sln files, such as opening the .aspx, .aspx.cs, .js, images, etc. manually in VS without opening or creating an actual project or solution.
4. The .csproj/.sln files are not missing. Whatever you experienced led you to the false belief the .csproj and .sln files would be missing. But in reality, whatever you saw and witnessed is an expression of another problem, not of the .csproj/.sln files missing.

Comment: @ASeriousMan: Currently my colleague who assist me to familiarize with projects is not in office. I am not sure how these 2 files are missing. Also I am looking at this particular project for first time. still i choose option 2 may be problem as now.

Comment: Thanks for your MCQ provided to me. best match is option 2 from your pick one.